# How to power multiple LED chips using single driver and several DC-DC CC converters

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter

I have 5 pieces of 100W LED chips but customs won't let me import 5 pieces of drivers to power them unless I pay a ridiculous sum. They are 100 Watt LED chips rated 30-35V @ 3A.

I cannot find 36V LED drivers locally, So I need to choose a 400 to 600W LED driver and use several DC-CC converters.

There are 12 to 48 Volt drivers available; which voltage would be a better choice? Should I go for a lower voltage driver (12V or 24V) and step-up converters or higher voltage driver (36V or 48V) and step down converters to obtain a more reliable and efficient system?

My gut tells me to go with a 36V-600W driver and add 5 pieces of DC buck converters but I am not sure if it would be a long term & reliable solution. Can I succesfully power these LEDs using [**this**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/182025826725) DC converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 600W, 36V LED driver circuit available to power 5 100w, 30-35V LEDs, why would you then need to use voltage converters?

LEDs actually don't care if you apply a source to them that is capable of an open-circuit voltage over their rated voltage; they only care how much current you allow through them.

This means that all you really need is a FET for each LED & a resistor/zener diode to set the current passed by the FETs in order to drive your LEDs from that 600W, 36V driver (or from any other 35-38V source that's capable of pushing the needed 15A). Something like this should work great:
[image: CC LED Driver x5]

PARTS:
* Zener Diode - [NZX3V3B,133](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/NZX3V3B,133/568-7962-1-ND/2762652)
* N-MOSFET - [IRLIZ14GPBF](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IRLIZ14GPBF/IRLIZ14GPBF-ND/811846)
* Resistor - [2K2, >=0.25W](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/resistors/through-hole-resistors/66690?FV=40408%2C80004%2C80005%2C80006%2C80029%2C80084%2C800b3%2C800b4%2C800b5%2C800bd%2C800bf%2C800c0%2C800c1%2C807de%2C1c0002%2C1c0003%2C1c0006%2C1c0011%2C1c0124%2Cfff40001%2Cfff80482&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=1&rohs=1&k=&quantity=10&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=100)
* Heat Sink - [530002B02500G](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/530002B02500G/HS380-ND/1216384)
* Total Bill Of Sale < $25USD

Comment: Isn't this branch voltage regulation and not current regulation?

Comment: @VoteCoffee Field Effect Transistors (FETs) Allow X amps to pass through when Y voltage is applied to their gate (Often termed as "voltage controlled current controllers"). Therefore, by using a FET with its gate biased in the linear working region, the transistor will only allow a set current through, almost regardless of the voltage across its source & drain pins (witin its safe working range, of course). That's what makex this a current-regulated circuit.